# How can I setup custom templates for a meta-data query

Tags: templates, post-meta

I have a post-meta field for Neighborhood.  I want to setup a url like: url.com/neighborhood/NEIGHBORHOOD-NAME

I know this would typically be handled by a CPT or custom taxonomy but it has to be done with a post-meta field in this case.

I also want this to use a custom template, not one of the standard templates.

I can easily link to the url but it returns a 404 page because nothing is associated with it.

Wordpress doesn't know what content to grab.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the core function [`add_*/get_query_arg()`](http://queryposts.com/function/add_query_arg/) that you can use to append stuff to the query and retrieve it.

So simply add a link somewhere, that points to your custom post types single.php template

```
single-{$custom_post_type}.php
```

Then append the query arg which would be `?wpse_meta_key=wpse_some_val` and then do a switch on top of your template:

```
if ( 'wpse_some_val' === get_query_arg( 'wpse_meta_key' ) )
{
    get_template_part( 'special_query_template' );
}
else
{
    // do default stuff
}
```